# Fill a 3D numpy array with ones based on a 2D array with indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have 2 numpy arrays `output` and `index`:

```
output = np.zeros((3,3,3))

>>>index   
array([[0,1,2],
       [1,0,0],
       [2,2,2]])
```

`index` represents the index until which `output` should be populated with ones in the first dimension. The populated value of `output` should look like:

```
>>>output 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],
       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],
       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]]
```

For example, since `index[0, 1] == 1`, we set `output[:1+1, 0, 1] = 1`. In general, if `index[i, j] == k`, we set `output[:k+1, i, j] = 1`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this in a vectorized manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we can create a mask of those places. So, simply convert that mask into an int array of `0s` and `1s`, like so -

```
(index >= np.arange(3)[:,None,None]).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [471]: index
Out[471]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2]])

In [472]: (index >= np.arange(3)[:,None,None]).astype(int)
Out[472]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
```

Alternatively, to assign into `output`, use the mask for `boolean-indexing` and assign `1s` -

```
output[index >= np.arange(output.shape[0])[:,None,None]] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `1` to the last position (along the first dimension) then back fill 0 with 1 using `np.maximum.accumulate`:

```
output[index, np.arange(output.shape[1])[:,None], np.arange(output.shape[2])] = 1  
np.maximum.accumulate(output[::-1], axis=0)[::-1]

#array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

#       [[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

#       [[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```